# Bootstrap 12 column syntax

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I write a bootstrap 12 column layout? This might be simple but it's nice to know the proper way of doing this.

`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>`

Comment: We really do want to help, but you should pay attention to spelling, markdown, etc (use the preview before posting), be clear in your question, include a full repro of what you've tried, and be specific in where you got stuck. (PS. It doesn't help that you demand we "spend a 3 seconds to comment" if it seems you haven't spend much more than that yourself on your question...)

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for your response. so the down-vote was for <`div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"></div>`. I wouldn't do that. thanks for your time for pointing out that. :) I've fixed that now.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you haven't read the (rather good) Bootstrap documentation.

Comment: There are many many resources available on this topic beginning with http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp Read through the guide and play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the bootstrap grid ["documentation"](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

to get 12 columns, you would need 12 seperate divs with the `.col-[size]-1` class

[Some more detailed documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

Comment: thanks. There should be a shorter way of doing this?

Comment: Not that I know of, but seeing as I only have a few months of web developing experience, I can't tell for sure.

Comment: You have linked to old documentation.

Comment: the answer I was looking for was given by AnnieMac and Fergaso. I was looking for a shorter version of the 12col laytout.

Comment: Just fixing a few quick things in case other people read this question, that's why I've edited my post even after you selected an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, you'd probably be okay just writing

```
<div class="col-md-12">
```

This would render the div at 12 cols across all viewports.

If for example you have a reason to want this div to render at 6 cols wide on small devices but remain at 12 on md you could use

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
```

to target the different viewport sizes... but do check out the (extensive) bootstrap documentation for further details